# Java Fx image update from imageView

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, imageview, blob

how to update image showing in imageView 
i set this image from database 
code to get image on imageView from db is...

```
InputStream is = resultSet.getBinaryStream("image");
OutputStream os;

os = new FileOutputStream(new File("src/sources/images/photo.jpg"));
byte[]content = new byte[1024];
int size = 0;
while((size=is.read(content))!= -1)
{
   os.write(content,0,size);
}
os.close();
is.close();
image  = new Image("file:src/sources/images/photo.jpg");

imageView.setImage(image);
```

image is saving in BLOB type in MySQL database

Now i want to update this image and set it again this image if i dont choose any image using file chooser
please solve my this problem 
thanks in advance

File chooser code

```
stage = (Stage) showScene.getScene().getWindow();

   file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

   if(file != null){
               image = new Image(file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toString(),imageView.getFitWidth(),imageView.getFitHeight(),true,true);
       imageView.setImage(image);
       imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
   }
  fis = new FileInputStream(file); // here i got error(null pointer exception) if i try to update withouting choosing image from filechooser
```

I pass *fis* to the preparedstatement to update and also insert

Comment: The question is unclear: There's no file chooser in the code, so you'll always not choose a file according to the info provided. Furthermore what prevents you from simply executing this code again to do the update?

Comment: I didnt give code of filechooser because i dont think that is required

Comment: the issue is how can i set this image to data base .... ok i try to explaine more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because if you don't choose a file with the FileChooser, your `file` variable is set to null.  This can be resolved by altering your if statement a little.

```
file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);

if (file == null) {
    file = new File("path/to/default/file")
}

image = new Image(file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toString(),imageView.getFitWidth(),imageView.getFitHeight(),true,true);
imageView.setImage(image);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```